# Why still accessible for member variable after destructor is called

Tags: c++

```
class Cls {
public:
Cls() {
}

Cls(int id)
: id(id)  {

}

~Cls() {
  id = 999;
  std::cout<<id<<" Bye!"<<std::endl;
}

int id;
char data[999999] = {0, };
};

int main() {
    Cls* cl3 = new Test(3);
    int* id = &(cl3->id);
    std::cout<<id<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<*id<<std::endl;
    delete cl3;
    std::cout<<id<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<*id<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why id is still accessible after t3 class is deleted?
To my knowledge, the destructor will delete all member variables.

Comment: How did expect it to "delete all member variables"? How do you propose to "delete" content stored in computer memory? Burn out memory chips? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Here's an analogy for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/817643

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Don't try to make sense of the behavior of the program.